# Getting the Google search terms from a https Google search

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I want to get the search terms that user typed on Google to get to my long-tail landing page (and use them on that page).

Getting the the "q" variable from the query string using the response referrer (in ASP C#) works well but only if the referring Google page was **not** loaded as https.

This is obviously a problem due to the fact that almost everyone is logged in to their Google accounts on their browsers all the time and, if they are, all Google pages will be automatically loaded (and redirected) to use https.

When a user (on **https**://www.google.com) searches for something and clicks on a search result, Google seems to redirect the user to an intermediate page that strips the request of its query string and replaces it with a different one that pretty much only contains url that the intermediate page should redirect to (i.e. the url to my long-tail landing page).

Is there any way that I can get the original search terms that were used on **https**://www.google.com anyway? Maybe if JavaScript could access the browser history or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way that I can get the original search terms that were used on **https**://www.google.com

No, the full text of the `https` session is secured via SSL this includes headers, urls etc. In your scenario, for security reasons browers tend to omit the `referer` header therefore you won't be able to access it (unless the destination URL is also secured via HTTPS). This is part of the HTTP spec - [15.1.3 Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3).

The only thing you can do is put a disclaimer on your site to say it doesn't work over https.

Comment: +1 for Disclaimer idea. Yea Disclaimer sounds good. But, I suppose he want's to keep a record of stuff? which again is impossible to be tracked if referred from HTTPS.

Comment: Referer headers are sent to the page the user visits after they visit the page with the URI in the referer header. The referer header to the site being linked to is not secured via SSL (unless the site being linked to is also using SSL). Browsers generally do not send referer headers when leaving SSL for security reasons, but it is "not being sent" that stops them being read, not "being encrypted with SSL".

Comment: Thanks for the responses, James, KarmicDice, and Quentin. So the disclaimer is not really the way I want to go with this. Getting the google search query was supposed to be more of a nice-to-have. The landing page works fine without it, but would be a little more dynamic with the search query. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is Google, it is not possible because there is not shared link with your website.

Once you are on HTTPS - it does *not allow* sending of REFERRER headers. I am sure you are aware that headers can be manipulated and cannot be trusted but, you *may* trust Google. However, due to privacy policy any activity done on Google by Google users are not shared by 3rd party. [Link](http://www.google.com/policies/privacy/)

Again, in server side languages you can find functions for HTTP Referrer but not HTTPS referrer. That is for a reason !

Unless and until you do not have a collaboration with the originating server who may create an exception in their RFC *thing* to allow HTTP REFERRER ONLY for your website. It isn't possible.

Hope that helps! (in moving on) :)

EDIT: [Wikipedia Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) See Referrer Hiding (2nd last line)

Comment: HTTP is still HTTP even it tunneled through SSL. Don't read too much into the name of the environment variable.

Comment: Yes but, I was talking in terms of convention :D You see this issue has been addressed by me couple of times in person to many people so, just wrote things as they popped. But, I am sure none of it is incorrect :)

Comment: Google's privacy policy has nothing to do with referer headers. It is browsers which are responsible for sending referers, not servers. A server cannot create an exception in "their RFC" - an RFC is a technical specification, not something that is set on a server-by-server basis.

Comment: @Quentin GOogle does mention that they wont share anything that we do... So, technically ending referrer should violate it. I had a discussion with my mate here, he agrees :) yea, RFC, I agree , u r right... 'their RFC' what I meant was RFC thing (if it was possible) to modify...

Answer (score 1):

To see the referrer data you need to be either a paying google ads customer (and the visitor come via an ad-click) or have your site in HTTPS as well. Certs are cheap these days or you could use an intermediary like CloudFlare to do the SSL and have a self-signed cert on your site.

You  can also see queries no matter the method used, with Google Webmaster tools.

I wrote a little about this here: http://blogs.dixcart.com/public/technology/2012/03/say-goodbye-to-keyword-tracking.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea Richard. I will look into it, but I don't think it really suits my needs. The users will land on the page through long tail search results, not paid ads.

Comment: @n1ck3 I did say "either", if you go HTTPS on your whole site, you will get the search strings without being an adwords customer.  Using the Google Webmaster tools you can also change all your indexed results to include the https, meaning you don't have to wait for a re-index.